# Conditionally apply CSS style when rendered on touch screen

Tags: css

I have a simple python-flask webpage which renders some card views in a flex container. I have defined a separate style for `css :hover` pseudo-class to increase shadow and slightly expand the card view. However, on touch screen - hover is triggered by dragging the pointer over the card, and if the touch stops outside of a card the hover effect remains until the next touch on the screen.

I would like to conditionally apply styling to hover, only when the device is not touch screen. For that I tried to use `css @media (pointer: coarse)` and `css @media (any-pointer: coarse)` as well as to combine `:hover` with `:active` and `:focus` as many answers to similar questions advised, but to no avail.

Making the decision based on screen size sounds like a bad idea for me, since it's not the size or any visible attributes I adjust here.

So how can I conditionally apply CSS styling based on whether the devices has touch screen or no?

The code for the page is below (it's a jinja template so it may not run as-is).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Browse Trees</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
 
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 70%; height: 80%; flex-grow: 0;">
        {%for tree in trees%}
        <div class="tree" onclick="window.location=('/tree/{{tree.id}}')">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='260-150x150.jpg')}}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>{{tree.latinName}}</b></h4>
                <p>{{tree.organization}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>

<style>


    .tree {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transition: 0.3s;
        border-radius: 5px;
        max-height: max-content;
        max-width: max-content;
        margin: 12px;
    }

    @media(any-pointer: fine) {
        .tree:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        }
    }
    
    

    .container {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        height: 150px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    img {
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        max-width: 260px;
        max-height: 260px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: @media (pointer: coarse) should work, can you provide full code? maybe there is problem with sth else

Comment: You are right that size of screen is irrelevant. There are some enormous touchscreens now. Also there are devices where a user may sometimes be using a touchscreen, sometimes a mouse etc. You could set a flag when the first touch is sensed, but that would mean that hybrid devices would react differently depending on whether the user has touched at some point or not - that might be somewhat confusing for a user that is employing both touch and mouse.

Comment: @Unlucky I did add the code as requested

Comment: @Unlucky I'm confused on why is it relevant? My question is about the @ media querry to get screen type, not about inlining it.